# strange javascript function behavior

Tags: javascript

here is little example from secrets of js ninja:

```
function addMethod(obj, methodName, fn) {
    const old = obj[methodName];


  obj[methodName] = function () {
    if (fn.length === arguments.length) {
      return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    } else if (typeof old === 'function') {
      return old.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
}

let ninja = {};

addMethod(ninja, 'whatever', a => console.log(`one: ${a}`));
ninja.whatever(1);
addMethod(ninja, 'whatever', (a,b) => console.log(a, b));
ninja.whatever(2, 2);
addMethod(ninja, 'whatever', (a,b, c) => console.log(a, b, c));
ninja.whatever(3);
console.log(ninja);
console.dir(addMethod);
```

and i can't understand why in this variable

```
const old = obj[methodName];
```

work as this function

```
a => console.log(`one: ${a}`)
```

i think there is must be this func

```
(a,b) => console.log(a, b)
```

because it was write in ol before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the 'old' functions keep on existing because **each call to 'addMethod' creates a distinct variable 'old'** (which is only accessible in the scope delimited by the 'addMethod' function body)

Answer (score 0):

Your's `addMethod` functions sets `obj[methodName]` to be

```
function () {
    if (fn.length === arguments.length) {
         return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    } else if (typeof old === 'function') {
         return old.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

Which is what you get....

Comment: yes, i know. I mean why this `ninja.whatever(2, 2);` isn't override variable old